# java image appears and disappears when using game loop

Tags: java, image, paint, game-loop

**game loop:**

```
private int FPS = 25;
private int targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

public void run(){

    init();

    long start;
    long elapsed;
    long wait;

    while (running){

        start = System.nanoTime();
        init();
        repaint();
        elapsed = System.nanoTime()  - start;

        wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

        try {

            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**the paint method:**

```
/**draws the game graphics*/
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    gameStateHandler.draw(g2);

}
```

**the method the that the paint method refers too:**

```
private static  Image image = resourceLoader.getImage("/background/menu_background.png");
/**draws the menu state*/
public static void draw(Graphics2D g){

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

i call the image from this method which is in the same folder of the image

```
static resourceLoader rl = new resourceLoader();

public static Image getImage(String image){

    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(rl.getClass().getResource(image));
}
```

i have a game loop that it will call `repaint();` 60 times per second and in the paint method it refers to a method where this method draws an image. everything seems nice and smooth and when i run the program the image appears and disappears at a fast time and sometimes the image appears and nothing bad happens but after a random amount of time the thing happens i changed the fps from low to high and from high to low still the same im using jpanel in this project

Comment: How/where is your `image` created/manipulated?

Comment: Sounds like a lack of double buffering http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Java%3aTutorials%3aDouble_Buffering

Comment: @weston Thought so too, but blitting an image to the canvas should be as fast as it gets for updating the display.

Comment: For double buffering, you may also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508042/how-do-you-double-buffer-in-java-for-a-game

Comment: @HannoBinder I found that too, but there are no really great answers on that question.

Comment: @HannoBinder yes I guess it's not a problem for this case, they effectively are double buffering.

Comment: I think we need to see more code, like Hanno said - where is the `image`, where is it being instantiated, why are we calling a method `draw()` (is it overloaded), and so on. If the OP is using a `Canvas`, too, I'd recommend dropping it for a `JPanel` and overriding `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`.

Comment: my image is an png type in the project root (aka res folder) i created from a program and i putted in the project root @HannoBinder

Comment: i edited and added the code in the question @Gorbles

Comment: Are you using a `Canvas`? What are you drawing onto?

Comment: no i'm using jpanel @Gorbles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there's a recommendation here, which could well be the fix you need:

**Use `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`**

```
// draws the game graphics

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;    
    gameStateHandler.draw(g2);    
}
```

`paintComponent` is the [recommended way to use JPanels to paint in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) - see also [a more detailed explanation of custom painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). It could well be that your use of `paint()` is what's causing your visual inconsistencies.

Failing that, I recommend looking at how you're loading your resource, but that should work, so I don't think it's the issue.

Comment: okay thanks but how do you call it in the gameloop ? sorry im a new programmer @Gorbles

Comment: This should be called by Swing when you invoke `repaint()` - it should be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Thread.sleep(). It can cause stutters if invoked on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

For swing you should use javax.swing.Timer:
1. Initialize the Timer with the required delay (your targetTime).
2. On timer actionPerformed() call repaint().

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` *can* cause stutters but will not presuming your target framerate is acceptable. Certainly, drawing one image to your screen will not cause unnecessary delay on vaguely-modern hardware, especially at the target rate of 25FPS. I'm not sure your advice will help here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In your game loop, after

```
 wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
```

add the line

```
 wait = Math.max(5L, wait);
```

to keep your wait time from getting too small or going negative.

Comment: it didnt fix the problem @Gilbert le blanc